# Why multiple threads are entering the synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was writing the thread ordering program and the execution has two methods "prevMethod" and "anotherMethod" executing within the same class and same monitor shared object "lock1" then why both threads are executing within same synchronized block, doesn't it defeats the purpose of a monitor object.

```
class Ordering extends Thread {
    SharedObject obj = null;
    boolean flag = false;

    private AtomicInteger counter;

    Ordering(String name, SharedObject obj, AtomicInteger counter) {
        super(name);
        this.obj = obj;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            prevMethod();
            System.out.println("New Method Started");
            anotherMethod();
        }
    }

    private void prevMethod() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Section 1");
            while (!obj.flag) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "
                            + counter.getAndIncrement());
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            obj.flag = true;
            obj.notify();
        }
    }

    private void anotherMethod() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Section 2");

            while (obj.flag) {

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "
                        + counter.getAndIncrement());
                try {
                    obj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            obj.flag = false;
            obj.notify();
        }
    }
}

public class SequencialPrinting {

    public static void main(String... arg) {
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(3);
        SharedObject lock1 = new SharedObject();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Ordering("Thread 1", lock1, counter));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Ordering("Thread 2", lock1, counter));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread-0 Section 1
Thread-0 3
Thread-1 Section 1
Thread-1 4
```

Comment: What does the javadoc of Object.wait() say?

Comment: Both your threads enter the block, call `wait()`, and then wait for ever. Short of spurious wakeups your code isn't going to do very much...

Comment: Also, your `Ordering extends Thread` then then you pass `new Ordering` to another `Thread`. Not sure what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @JBNizet but shouldn't the synchronized block prevent another thread from entering the block.

Comment: Again, what does the javadoc of Object.wait() say?

Comment: The output does not show that the threads are in the block *at the same time*.

Comment: @StephenC the code says they are though...

Comment: @JBNizet the doc says the current thread should hold the monitor object and it will be released only when wait() or notify() happens, but still, the code is within the scope of the synchronized block, therefore another thread should not enter.

Comment: There's a `wait()`. So each thread enteres the block and then suspends.

Comment: @Prashant it **does not** say that. Please read the documentation much more carefully, specifically it says "_This method causes the current thread..._"; what does it cause the current thread to do?

Comment: @BoristheSpider that means the synchronized is ineffective, moreover using "this" also produces the same result.

Comment: If the thread **releases the lock** when calling wait(), then any other thread can enter a synchronized block locked on that lock, since no other thread holds it. That's what releasing a lock is about. How could you ever notify a thread, since you need a lock to notify, if wait didn't release the lock?

Comment: Ah yes.  I see.  (But the are not "in the block" in the sense of holding the lock.  But that is what you are saying.)

Comment: @Prashant don't quite see your point.

Comment: @Prashant - it doesn't mean that it is ineffective.  Indeed, if the lock wasn't released by `wait()`, then the other thread would not be able to `notify()` the thread ... because it wouldn't be able to acquire the lock on the object.  The wait / notify mechanism has been carefully designed so that can be use to implement thread-safe conditional notification.  If the locking wasn't done like this, there would be race conditions.

Comment: ok.. now i see the point.

Comment: Ordering should not extend `Thread`, it should implement `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

First Thread calls the prevMethod(), prints

Thread-0 Section 1
Thread-0 3

and calls wait(), then releases the lock.

Second thread calls the prevMethod()

and prints

Thread-1 Section 1
Thread-1 4

Where two threads are entering the synchronized block. Only one thread is entering the synchronozed block at a time

Answer (score -2):

I have never seen code like that... doing new Thread and passing to the constructor another new Thread...
You should consider either 1) Ordering should just implement Runnable or 2) in your main, just create a new Ordering (which is a thread) and start it.

So this is what happened in your code:
"Thread-0" started executing prevMethod, when it hit the synchronized statement it got the monitor (it now owned it). ("Thread-1" might have now been stuck on the same synchronized statement) anyway, "Thread-0" printed "Thread-0 Section 1" and "Thread-0 3". Then it executed wait on the monitor. **wait gives up the monitor**, so now "Thread-0" has given up the monitor and is waiting for a notify. Now that "Thread-0" is no longer the owner of the monitor it can be given to "Thread-1" who's been stuck on the synchronized statement. now "Thread-1" goes thru the synchronized statement (becoming the owner of the shared obj) and prints out the enxt 2 lines and then also gives up the monitor...

Comment: Consider formatting your answer is a more pleasant way than the impenetrable block style. Further, it would be worth backing up your explanation with some documentation about how `wait` behaves. Finally, your first paragraph is really an aside - the fact that the OP is using a `Thread` as a `Runnable` to pass to another `Thread` is really just odd, not important - treat it as such, place that comment at the end of your answer, perhaps with a suggestion for improvement.

Comment: Answering poor (downvoted) questions with a poor answer is likely to just attract downvoters for your answer.

Comment: Interesting that this answer resulted in negative feedback due to style and formating, ignoring substance, and in fact it contains all other answers that came after this answer